# Visual Studio Error C2327

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have the following code snippet:

```
template < class MOEOT >
struct comp
{
    bool operator() (const MOEOT & a, const MOEOT & b)
    {
        return  ((a.objectiveVector()[1] < b.objectiveVector()[1]) || ((a.objectiveVector()[1] == b.objectiveVector()[1]) && (a.objectiveVector()[0] < b.objectiveVector()[0])));
    }
};

template < class MOEOT >
class moeo2DMinHypervolumeArchive : public std::set<MOEOT , comp < MOEOT > >
{
public:

    typedef typename std::set < MOEOT, comp<MOEOT>  >::iterator Iterator;

};
```

I'm compiling in VS 2013, and get the following error:

```
Error   1   error C2327: 'std::_Tree_comp<_Pr_has_storage,_Traits>::comp' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
```

From what I've read elsewhere, this seems to be a bug in the VC. The common solution is to put the typedef outside the class. However, this does not work in my case, since the typedef itself contains a template argument from the class. Hence, putting the typedef outside does not work.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: use `::comp<MOEOT>` when declaring your nested typedef. Alternatively, rename your `comp` class template to something else, like `my_special_comp`.

Long(er) answer: this behaviour is a result of MSVC's non-standard behaviour when looking up names inside template definitions - what's commonly referred to as *two-phase lookup*.

Basically, that `_Tree_comp` that appears in the error message is an indirect base of `std::set` in the standard library implementation that ships with Visual C++ 2013. It so happens that it has a non-static data member called `comp`. When looking up the unqualified name `comp` that you're using in the nested typedef, MSVC incorrectly looks inside dependent bases and finds that declaration. It is indeed an error according to the standard, but it's well-known behaviour for MSVC (they are looking at fixing it in the future, but don't hold your breath).

`::comp`, on the other hand, is a qualified-id, and it has to be looked up in the global namespace, thus avoiding the name clash.

---

As a side note, the implementation of `std::set` in the standard library that ships with Visual C++ 2015 RC has changed and no longer causes this particular problem (lookup is still broken, but the name `comp` just isn't there anymore to cause the problem).

Comment: Fixed in MSVC 2015.